# how to install numba on pypy3, or pypy3 does not support numba?

Tags: numba, pypy

I am trying to install numba on pypy3 as my program is with some numba decroated functions, but when I simply call pypy3 -m pip install numba, it failed.
Does pypy3 support numba?

Answer (score 0):

No, until now it doesn't work. `pypy3 -m pip install numba` fails because `llvmlite` cannot be configured.

But there's a workaround - and it won't get any prizes:

**The 1st file, run with pypy3:**

```
import subprocess

i = input("Double this value: ")

n = subprocess.check_output(f"python3 double.py {i}", shell=True)

n = str(n)

n = n.replace("b'", "")
n = n.replace("\\n\'", "")
n = int(n)

print(f"The value now is: {n}")
```

**This one is run with python3, and uses numba:**

```
import numba
import sys

in_value = sys.argv[1]

in_value = int(in_value)

@numba.jit
def double(in_value):
    
    return(in_value * 2)

print(double(in_value))
```